# Hide Fragment when Activity is launched, display when clicked

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have MapActivity, on which I have to display a fragment when infowindow is clicked. When MapActivity is launched, I dont want the fragment to be visible. When I click on an infoWindow, I want the fragment to appear.

MapActivity.java

```
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

    android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager ();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
            .beginTransaction ();
    fragmentOnMap = new FragmentOnMap();
    fragmentOnMap.setSpecialText("Hello Fragment");
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragmentinmap,fragmentOnMap);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

MapActivity Layout file

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.ather.healthapp.MapActivity" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id = "@+id/fragmentinmap"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:background="#fefeff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:translationY="400dp"
/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Fragment Activity

```
public class FragmentOnMap extends Fragment {

String specialText;
//public FrameLayout frameLayout;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
    TextView textView= (TextView) rootView.findViewById (R.id.fragmen_title);
    textView.setText (specialText);
    return rootView;
}
```

And Fragment Layout File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:padding="10dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fragmen_title"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"

    android:textSize="20dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/TakeTest"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Test" />

</LinearLayout>
```

When MapActivity is launched, fragment is not displayed, which is fine. But when I click on an InfoWindow, it doesnt show up. I dont want any animation at the moment. Just simply display the fragment and hide when I click outside.

Your help will be appreciated.

EDIT

After some further research, I have added slide_Up.xml to my anim folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
android:fromYDelta="75%p"
android:toYDelta="0%p"
android:fillAfter="true"
android:duration="500"/>
</set>
```

I guess now I have to call some animation

```
 Animation slideup = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_up);
```

but where? in onInfoWindow method? How do i startanimation there

Comment: Try getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(fragment_class) method.

Comment: And where would I use this? Fragment is already hidden on map.

Comment: Adding getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().show(fragmentOnMap); in onInfowindowClicked method doesnt help

Comment: Try to use v4 support library, and use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead.

Comment: Whats the problem in my code?

Comment: I want the fragment to show when I click on the infoWindow, and then pull up half way.

Comment: You can add animation by using the `setCustomAnimations(enter, exit);` method.

Comment: So there will be another xml for slide down, and I will call this animation in oninfowindowclicked method?